# InvalidProtocolBufferException in Java client when deserializing protobuf data from C++ server

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, protobuf-java

I have a protobuf message like this:

```
message Update {
  Path path = 1;                      // The path (key) for the update.
  Value value = 2 [deprecated=true];  // The value (value) for the update.
  TypedValue val = 3;                 // The explicitly typed update value.
}

// TypedValue is used to encode a value being sent between the client and
// target (originated by either entity).

message TypedValue {
    oneof value {
        string string_val = 1;            // String value.
        int64 int_val = 2;                // Integer 
        ....
        google.protobuf.Any any_val = 9;  // protobuf.Any encoded bytes.
        ....
  }
}
```

On the server side (C++), we are setting this field as follows (LLDP is the outer class and Interfaces is inside that):

```
   openconfig_lldp::Lldp out;
   GetLldpProto(&out);

   update->mutable_val()->mutable_any_val()->PackFrom(out.interfaces());
```

On the client side (Java), we are extracting this field like this:

```
OpenconfigLldp.Lldp.Interfaces interfaces = update.getVal().getAnyVal().unpack(OpenconfigLldp.Lldp.Interfaces.class);
```

This is throwing a InvalidProtocolBufferException exception. When I dump the "update" in my Java client, I see this:

```
path {
  elem {
    name: "lldp"
  }
  elem {
    name: "interfaces"
  }
}
val {
  any_val {
    type_url: "type.googleapis.com/openconfig_lldp.Lldp.Interfaces"
    value: "\212\207\237\334\v\374\001\022\371\001\262\211\267l\031\342\367\304\260\002\v\n\tEth 1/1/1\242\340\247\230\017\002\b\001\352\316\234\250\017\324\001\262\217\304\272\017/\022-\302\340\317\247\001\'\202\225\377\302\001\b\n\006Neigh1\342\253\214\353\001\v\n\tEth 1/1/1\242\364\301\261\a\002\b\n\262\217\304\272\017/\022-\302\340\317\247\001\'\202\225\377\302\001\b\n\006Neigh2\342\253\214\353\001\v\n\tEth 1/1/2\242\364\301\261\a\002\b\n\262\217\304\272\017/\022-\302\340\317\247\001\'\202\225\377\302\001\b\n\006Neigh3\342\253\214\353\001\v\n\tEth 1/1/3\242\364\301\261\a\002\b\n\262\217\304\272\017/\022-\302\340\317\247\001\'\202\225\377\302\001\b\n\006Neigh4\342\253\214\353\001\v\n\tEth 1/1/4\242\364\301\261\a\002\b\n\212\207\237\334\v\374\001\022\371\001\262\211\267l\031\342\367\304\260\002\v\n\tEth 1/1/2\242\340\247\230\017\002\b\001\352\316\234\250\017\324\001\262\217\304\272\017/\022-\302\340\317\247\001\'\202\225\377\302\001\b\n\006Neigh1\342\253\214\353\001\v\n\tEth 1/1/1\242\364\301\261\a\002\b\n\262\217\304\272\017/\022-\302\340\317\247\001\'\202\225\377\302\001\b\n\006Neigh2\342\253\214\353\001\v\n\tEth 1/1/2\242\364\301\261\a\002\b\n\262\217\304\272\017/\022-\302\340\317\247\001\'\202\225\377\302\001\b\n\006Neigh3\342\253\214\353\001\v\n\tEth 1/1/3\242\364\301\261\a\002\b\n\262\217\304\272\017/\022-\302\340\317\247\001\'\202\225\377\302\001\b\n\006Neigh4\342\253\214\353\001\v\n\tEth 1/1/4\242\364\301\261\a\002\b\n\212\207\237\334\v\374\001\022\371\001\262\211\267l\031\342\367\304\260\002\v\n\tEth 1/1/3\242\340\247\230\017\002\b\001\352\316\234\250\017\324\001\262\217\304\272\017/\022-\302\340\317\247\001\'\202\225\377\302\001\b\n\006Neigh1\342\253\214\353\001\v\n\tEth 1/1/1\242\364\301\261\a\002\b\n\262\217\304\272\017/\022-\302\340\317\247\001\'\202\225\377\302\001\b\n\006Neigh2\342\253\214\353\001\v\n\tEth 1/1/2\242\364\301\261\a\002\b\n\262\217\304\272\017/\022-\302\340\317\247\001\'\202\225\377\302\001\b\n\006Neigh3\342\253\214\353\001\v\n\tEth 1/1/3\242\364\301\261\a\002\b\n\262\217\304\272\017/\022-\302\340\317\247\001\'\202\225\377\302\001\b\n\006Neigh4\342\253\214\353\001\v\n\tEth 1/1/4\242\364\301\261\a\002\b\n\212\207\237\334\v\374\001\022\371\001\262\211\267l\031\342\367\304\260\002\v\n\tEth 1/1/4\242\340\247\230\017\002\b\001\352\316\234\250\017\324\001\262\217\304\272\017/\022-\302\340\317\247\001\'\202\225\377\302\001\b\n\006Neigh1\342\253\214\353\001\v\n\tEth 1/1/1\242\364\301\261\a\002\b\n\262\217\304\272\017/\022-\302\340\317\247\001\'\202\225\377\302\001\b\n\006Neigh2\342\253\214\353\001\v\n\tEth 1/1/2\242\364\301\261\a\002\b\n\262\217\304\272\017/\022-\302\340\317\247\001\'\202\225\377\302\001\b\n\006Neigh3\342\253\214\353\001\v\n\tEth 1/1/3\242\364\301\261\a\002\b\n\262\217\304\272\017/\022-\302\340\317\247\001\'\202\225\377\302\001\b\n\006Neigh4\342\253\214\353\001\v\n\tEth 1/1/4\242\364\301\261\a\002\b\n"
  }
}
```

The type_url seems correct to me. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for your time.

### EDIT #1:

I looked at the exception string. It is "Type of the Any message does not match the given class."

The same proto file is used for C++ and Java, but I see "openconfig_lldp.Lldp.Interfaces" in C++, where as, it is "OpenconfigLldp.Lldp.Interfaces" in Java. Need to find out why..

### EDIT #2:

The same .proto file is used. In this case, it is:

```
openconfig_lldp.proto
---------------------
syntax = "proto3";

package openconfig.openconfig_lldp;

message Lldp {
    message Config {
        ....
        ....
    }
    ....
    ....
}
```

In case of Java, I see the parent class as OpenconfigLldp in a package called openconfig_lldp.

```
package openconfig.openconfig_lldp;

public final class OpenconfigLldp {
  private OpenconfigLldp() {}
  ....
  ....
  /**
   * Protobuf type {@code openconfig.openconfig_lldp.Lldp}
   */
  public  static final class Lldp extends com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3 implements
    // @@protoc_insertion_point(message_implements:openconfig.openconfig_lldp.Lldp)
   ....
   ....
}
```

In C++, I don't see any class called "OpenconfigLldp" generated. Instead it is just "Lldp"

So, the type_url in the Any.protobuf is a mismatch. C++ side puts it as

```
type_url: "type.googleapis.com/openconfig_lldp.Lldp.Interfaces"
```

While in the Java side I use:

```
OpenconfigLldp.Lldp.Interfaces interfaces = update.getVal().getAnyVal().unpack(OpenconfigLldp.Lldp.Interfaces.class);
```

Anyone has thoughts on why there is a wrapper class in Java protoc output?

### EDIT #3

Apparently looks like it is because of the "outer_class_name". In the Java code, I have an outer class "OpenconfigLldp".

The type_url format is:

```
type.googleapis.com/packagename.messagename
```

So, C++ code sets this to openconfig_lldp.Lldp.Interfaces.
But, this maps to OpenconfigLldp.Lldp.Interfaces in Java.

How could I work around this?

### FINAL EDIT and FINAL QUESTION

After some digging around, this is what I found out.
By default, type_url is:

```
type_url: "type.googleapis.com/openconfig_lldp.Lldp.Interfaces"
```

On the Java side, I looked at the Any implementation. It tries to compare this with:

```
openconfig.openconfig_lldp.Lldp.Interfaces
```

I found this out by printing:

```
Lldp.Interfaces defaultInstance = (Lldp.Interfaces)Internal.getDefaultInstance(Lldp.Interfaces.class);
logger.info("full descriptor name: " + defaultInstance.getDescriptorForType().getFullName());
```

So, I hacked the C++ side to send:

```
update->mutable_val()->mutable_any_val()->set_type_url(std::string("type.googleapis.com/openconfig.openconfig_lldp.Lldp.Interfaces"));
```

So, I think I know what is happening here!

Thanks for reading through all the edits.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand correctly what's going wrong -- ideally the qualified names would be in protocol buffer namespaces -- language specific mappings shouldn't matter.

If the question is still open, I'd recommend to move the core of it to the top, preserving the edits as "what I have done so far".

Perhaps this is some kind of bug that could be worked around with on of these options:

- `java_multiple_files`
- `java_outer_classname`

More details about these options can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3